# html-agility-pack how can i make import url's local using selectnodes?

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I am using html-agility-pack to change all the website url's to local url's. I've already changed several url's with SelectNodes. However I have no idea how to use import url's with selectnodes.

I want to change this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
    @import url("http://link.nl/test.css");
    @import url("http://link2.nl/test2.css");
    @import url("http://link3.nl/test3.css");
    @import url("http://link4.nl/test4.css");
</style>
```

to this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
    @import url("c:/user/admin/documents/copy1.css");
    @import url("c:/user/admin/documents/copy2.css");
    @import url("c:/user/admin/documents/copy3.css");
    @import url("c:/user/admin/documents/copy4.css");
</style>
```

Does anyone know how I can change this to a local path file with html-agility-pack?

Comment: HtmlAgilityPcak doesn't understand CSS expression. In HAP point of view, content of `<style>` is just a single text node. You have to parse the text further using something else, regex for example. Can you post the expected output for the above HTML snippet

Comment: @har07 I updated my question with additional info